# Find a dart package that can edit audio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, package

I am looking for a dart package that can utilize functions such as detune.

web audio API is the most similar but I can't use it in app development

Are there any packages that support similar functions to web audio API?

Comment: You might find it easiest to use FFI to call a C(++) library: https://superpowered.com/audio-library-list

Answer (score -1):

try this package **

> on_audio_edit

**
https://pub.dev/packages/on_audio_edit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).